# Getting dimensions of Element with image inside that loads late

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm currently struggeling with getting the width of a element 'slides' by using `offsetWidth`.

```
var slide = $('.slides');

console.log(slide[0].offsetWidth);
console.log(slide[1].offsetWidth);
```

all the Elements in slides have a different width. However it returns the same value for all Elements and thats only true for the first Element.

The Elements have a `width: min-content` property.

```
.slides{
    width: min-content;
}
```

Inside the 'slides' Elements is a `<img>` Element and each has a individual aspect ratio but the same height.

```
.slides img{
    max-width: inherit;
    height: 35vw;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual markup? Or at least create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example. The individual `.slides` may have the same width, but the inner elements may not: however that is not clear until you update your question with more details.

Comment: Ok the Problem was that the images get loaded after they are in the viewport. Before that the `slides` are the same size. Thank you anyways. should i delete the question?

Comment: If you've solved it yourself you could either: close the question or post an answer.  You might like to make the title more "findable" for the problem if posting an answer.  But either way, thank you for updating with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved.

If you have the same issue, check if the content inside the child doesn't get loaded late. Like in my case the image inside gets loaded after it is in the viewport. That means it hasn't had a width until then.

I solved it that way:

this code snipped waits for the images to load in order to get the width

```
var counter = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    images_length = $('.gallery-image').length;
    //i needed to wait until all images have loaded so i picked the last image that fires the last event.
    $('.gallery-image').on("load", function() {
        if(counter == images_length -1){
            var slides = $('.gallery-slide', this);
            for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                 console.log(slides[i].offsetWidth);
            }
        }
        counter++;
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you also have a "solution" to the problem?  Eg what event do you wait on for the images to be loaded?

Comment: I'm working on it. If i find a suitable solution i will share it. Unfortunately the solution could be too specific in my case because im using an 'Imageoptimizer'.

Comment: Something here might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+image+loaded+event